# UIScrollView not scrolling when add constrains for UIPageControl in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I have 1 `UIPageControl` and 1  `UIScrollView`. When I set constrains for `UIPageControl`, my `UIScrollView` cannot scroll. This is my code:

```
//set contentsize for uiscrollview
[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,  1440)];

UIPageControl *imagePVControl = self.imagePVControl;
[imagePVControl setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[imagePVControl]-0-|"
                                                                  options:0  
                                                                  metrics:nil 
                                                                    views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(imagePVControl)]];
```

When I use `[imagePVControl setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];` **the scrollview cannot scroll**, but if I use `[imagePVControl setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];`, my **scrollview can srcoll**. Can you please help me to fix this issue. Thanks.

Also, my XIB is uncheck "Use Autolayout""
.

**UPDATE**

I change to my code as below. The `UIScrollview` can scroll but the `UIPageControl` is aligned in the center not the left. I want to algin the `UIPageControl` in the left but it is not successful. Please help me to correct it. Thanks

```
NSDictionary *views = @{@"ScrollImageView":self.scrollViewImage,@"TableView":self.productDetailTable,@"InfoView":self.infoView};

            NSDictionary *metrics = @{ @"ScrollImageheight" : ScrollImage_height,@"Tablewidth" : width, @"Tableheight" : Table_height,@"infoViewheight" : InfoView_height,@"infoViewWidth" : InfoView_width};

            [self.scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[TableView(Tablewidth)]-0-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];

            [self.scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[InfoView(infoViewWidth)]-0-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];

            [self.scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[ScrollImageView(ScrollImageheight)]-0-[InfoView(infoViewheight)]-0-[TableView(Tableheight)]-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];


            [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[imagePVControl]-0-|" options:0  metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(imagePVControl)]];
```

Comment: share a screenshot of IB

Comment: What about other constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I am also struggling with constraints in the UIScrollView. What I learn recently is that, once you set `TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`to NO, you will lose a lot of settings. Like `contentSize` and the frames of views inside the `UIScrollView`, that's weird. 
What I learnt is that if you want to add constraint to the views inside a `UIScrollView`, you have to set everything of whoseViews. 
In your case, I think you should try this way:
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[imagePVControl(320)]-0-|", options:0, metrics:nil, views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(imagePVControl)]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[imagePVControl(1440)]-0-|", options:0, metrics:nil, views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(imagePVControl)]];
In these two constraints, I specify the top, bottom, left and right, besides that, I also set the width and the height of the `imagePVControl`
The reason here is that, once you set the `TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to NO, you tell the computer that you are going to tell it how big the `contentSize` is, instead of setting the `contentSize`, you tell it all the information of the views inside the content. The main difference here is that `UIScrollView` does not have a fixed edge around it, so you can not set constraints as other kinds of `UIView`.*

*You could learn from this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html
Hope this help :)*

After reviewing this problem, I found the problem. The way you treat with `UIPageControl` was right, you should add a few more code here.
I assume that you have a `UIView` called myView in the top of the scrollview, and then you have a `UITableView` called myTable below myView. And you want to set myView 240 height, and myTable 1200 height. Then here is the code:

```
NSDictionary *viewsDic = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(myView, myTable);
[self.scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[myView(320)]-|", options:0, metrics:nil, views:viewDic]];
[self.scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[myTable(320)]-|", options:0, metrics:nil, views:viewDic]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[myView(240)]-[myTable(1200)]-|", options:0, metrics:nil, views:viewDic]];
```

The main reason is that you set a subview of the scrollView `TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to NO, this will make the contentSize unable to be manually set. So I give out the how big the content of scrollView will be, it automatically calculates the contentSize.

Comment: THanks, I tried your code, the scrollview can scroll but the content size is not correct and the UIPageControl is not shown.

Comment: Then what is all the views in that scrollview? You don't only have one UIPageControl, right?

Comment: Yes, i have uitableview, uipagecontroler and uiview in scrollview.

Comment: Then I think you should make your scrollview fulfilled with these three views. The contentSize is decided by those views, once you set the TranslateAutoresizengMaskIntoConstraints to NO, you can't set contentSize to the size you want.

Comment: Can you example code please? I'm a newbie in iOS. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I tried your code, the scrollview can scroll but the UIPageconrol is aligned  in the center, but i want it in the left. Can you help me to correct my code. I have updated my code in my question. Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is here:
`[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[imagePVControl]-0-|" options:0  metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(imagePVControl)]];`
Try this :
`[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[imagePVControl]-300-|" options:0  metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(imagePVControl)]];`
Because you align your PVControl left as 10 px to the rootview and right is 0 px to the rootview, so your PVControl is in the center.

Answer (score 0):

Why use constraints?  why can't you `setPagingEnabled:YES` on `UIScrollView` and then place `UIPageControl` on top of your `UIScrollView` in the hierarchy?

Comment: Because i want to align left for UIPageControl. But when i set constrain for it, my scrollview cannot scroll.